# Parsing dict with nested dict of lists

Tags: python

I am trying to parse the following dict

```
{'IsTruncated': False,
    'MaxItems': '100',
    'ResourceRecordSets': [{'Name': 'test.com.',
        {'Name': '1.test.com.',
        'ResourceRecords': [{'Value': '10.0.0.1'}],
        {'Name': '2.test.com.',
        'ResourceRecords': [{'Value': '10.0.0.2'}],
}
```

The output I am looking for is:

```
1.test.com    10.0.0.1
2.test.com    10.0.0.2
```

I have tried:

```
for resource in response['ResourceRecordSets']:
    print("{}  {}".format(resource['Name'], resource['ResourceRecords'] ))
```

and

```
for resource in response['ResourceRecordSets']:
    print("{}  {}".format(resource['Name'], resource['ResourceRecords'][0] ))
```

Is there a simple way to access this dict key/values within the nested list?

Comment: The code for your dict doesn't work.

Comment: the sample dictionary is incorrectly constructed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your dictionary should look like this:

```
{'IsTruncated': False,
'MaxItems': '100',
'ResourceRecordSets': [
    {'Name': 'test.com.', 
    'ResourceRecords' : [{'Value' : '<mising ip addr>'}]},
    {'Name': '1.test.com.',
    'ResourceRecords': [{'Value': '10.0.0.1'}]},
    {'Name': '2.test.com.',
    'ResourceRecords': [{'Value': '10.0.0.2'}]},
    ]
```

Try this:

```
for resource in response['ResourceRecordSets']:
    print("{}  {}".format(resource['Name'], resource['ResourceRecords'][0]['Value']))
```

Comment: don't you think this will fail on this dictionary as sample dictionary is incorrectly constructed

Comment: @prashantrana yeah it definitely will.